# Failed to purge the temporary install directory

Tags: ddev

I'm getting an error when running `ddev composer create drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev --stability dev --no-interaction`

```
...
Removing temporary install directory 
Failed to purge the temporary install directory /Users/.../my-drupal8-site/.tmp_ddev_composer_create_VjDray: open /Users/.../my-drupal8-site/.tmp_ddev_composer_create_VjDray: no such file or directory
```

[Full log](https://gist.github.com/amitaibu/b398291373663fbc5402025af5c3ec67)

[Config file](https://gist.github.com/amitaibu/20e8f8d79eca0db06eadb7b87625a3d7)

Mac OS 10.11.6

```
ddev version
bgsync          drud/ddev-bgsync:v1.6.0       
cli             v1.6.0                        
commit          v1.6.0                        
db              drud/ddev-dbserver:v1.6.0-10.2
dba             drud/phpmyadmin:v1.6.0        
ddev-ssh-agent  drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.6.0    
docker          18.06.1-ce                    
docker-compose  1.22.0                        
domain          ddev.local                    
router          drud/ddev-router:v1.6.0       
web             drud/ddev-webserver:v1.6.0
```

Comment: First... it doesn't actually do any harm if it fails to purge that temp install directory, but some more info please: What OS are you on? What version of ddev? Are you using NFS? webcache? Maybe you could gist your config.yaml.

Comment: rfay - I'm so happy to you have back around! :)

I've updated the OP.

Comment: I confirm this bug, must be new in v1.6.0. Could you please create an issue and link to it here? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the issue. This is prioritized in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1457

Comment: This was solved in ddev v1.7.0 so should no longer be an issue.